# Java Folder Structure

Tags: java

I need information on **java installation directory structure**.
 I have installed jdk7.0 suppose in c drive.
 There are different folders in java folder in c drive.
 Can anyone please tell me the importance of each folder

---

Following is the folder structure:

```
1. jdk1.7.0_21
├── bin  
├── include    
├── jre   
├── lib   
└── Other files         

2. jre7  
├── bin  
└── lib
```

Comment: You installed JRE when installing JDK right ? that's why you show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JRE under `jdk1.7.0_21/jre` and `jre7` are same except, the earlier is used by development tools and the later is used for all java application available to end user.

this document details about all internal folders. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdkfiles.html

Answer (score 0):

1. JDK - The Java Development Kit folder - this contains files used for development, but not for running Java applications.
2. JRE - The Java Runtime Environment folder - this contains everything needed for running Java applications, but not for developing them.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Java 7 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdkfiles.html):

> **c:\jdk1.7.0**
>
> ```
> Root directory of the JDK software installation. Contains copyright, license, and README files. Also contains src.zip, the archive of source code for the Java platform.
> ```
>
> **c:\jdk1.7.0\bin**
>
> ```
> Executable files for the development tools contained in the Java Development Kit. The PATH environment variable should contain an entry for this directory. For more information on the tools, see the JDK Tools.
> ```
>
> **c:\jdk1.7.0\lib**
>
> ```
> Files used by the development tools. These include the following:
>
>     tools.jar: Contains non-core classes for support of the tools and utilities in the JDK
>     dt.jar: DesignTime archive of BeanInfo files that tell interactive development environments (IDEs) how to display the Java components and how to let the developer customize them for an application
>     ant-javafx.jar: Contains Ant tasks for packaging JavaFX applications; see Packaging in Deploying JavaFX Applications
> ```
>
> **c:\jdk1.7.0\jre**
>
> ```
> Root directory of the Java runtime environment used by the JDK development tools. The runtime environment is an implementation of the Java platform. This is the directory represented by the java.home system property.
> ```
>
> **c:\jdk1.7.0\jre\bin**
>
> ```
> Executable files and DLLs for tools and libraries used by the Java platform. The executable files are identical to files in /jdk1.7.0/bin. The java launcher tool serves as an application launcher (and replaced the old jre tool that shipped with 1.1 versions of the JDK). This directory does not need to be in the PATH
> ```
>
> environment variable.
>
> **c:\jdk1.7.0\jre\bin\client**
>
> ```
> Contains the DLL files used by the Java HotSpot™ Client Virtual Machine.
> ```
>
> **c:\jdk1.7.0\jre\bin\server**
>       Contains the DLL files used by the Java HotSpot™ Server Virtual Machine.
>
> **c:\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib**
>       Code libraries, property settings, and resource files used by the Java runtime environment. For example:
>
> ```
>     rt.jar: Bootstrap classes (the RunTime classes that comprise the Java platform's core API)
>     charsets.jar: Character conversion classes
>     jfxrt.jar: JavaFX runtime libraries
>
> Aside from the ext subdirectory (described below) there are several additional resource subdirectories not described here.
> ```
>
> **c:\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext**
>
> ```
> Default installation directory for Extensions to the Java platform.
>
>     localedata.jar -- locale data for java.text and java.util.
> ```
>
> **c:\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\security**
>
> ```
> Contains files used for security management. These include the security policy (java.policy) and security properties (java.security)
> ```
>
> files.
>
> **c:\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\applet**
>       Jar files containing support classes for applets can be placed in the lib/applet/ directory. This reduces startup time for large applets by allowing applet classes to be pre-loaded from the local file system by the applet class loader, providing the same protections as if they had been downloaded over the net.
>
> **c:\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\fonts**
>
> ```
> Contains TrueType font files for use by the platform.
> ```